# Data aparecendo em 1 post só

Tags: wordpress, post, data

Olá galera estou com um problema que quando eu faço varias postagens no mesmo dia que seria a mesma data ela só aparece no ultimo post

.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
    <article  id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class( 'cf' ); ?> role="article">

                             <?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' ); ?>

                          <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">      <div class="box-index" style=" background-image:url(<?php echo $image[0];?>); "></div></a>

                               <b><a class="index-tro"href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></b><br />
                              <div class="datee"> <?php the_date(); ?> </div> 
                                <div class="linhapon"></div>
                                <h2 class="resum"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></h2>
                                <!--<?php
    if ( get_the_post_thumbnail( $post_id ) != '' ) {
        the_post_thumbnail();
    } else {
        echo get_first_image();
    }
?>-->

                            </article>
```

Comment: Isso aí é wordpress?

Comment: sim isso é wordpress @rray

Answer (score -1):

Olá, tente usar...

```
echo get_the_date();
```

no lugar de

```
the_date();
```